# How to download a sentinel images from google earth engine using python API in tfrecord

Tags: python-3.x, tiff, tfrecord, google-earth-engine, sentinel2

While trying to download sentinel image for a specific location, the tif file is generated by default in drive but its not readable by openCV or PIL.Image().Below is the code for the same. If I use the file format as tfrecord. There are no Images downloaded in the drive.

```
starting_time = '2018-12-15' 
delta = 15  
L = -96.98  
B = 28.78  
R = -97.02  
T = 28.74

cordinates = [L,B,R,T] 
my_scale = 30 
fname = 'sinton_texas_30'


llx = cordinates[0] 
lly = cordinates[1] 
urx = cordinates[2] 
ury = cordinates[3]

geometry = [[llx,lly], [llx,ury], [urx,ury], [urx,lly]]

tstart = datetime.datetime.strptime(starting_time, '%Y-%m-%d') tend =
tstart+datetime.timedelta(days=delta)
collSent = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2').filterDate(str(tstart).split('')[0], str(tend).split(' ')[0]).filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20)).map(mask2clouds)


medianSent = ee.Image(collSent.reduce(ee.Reducer.median())) cropLand = ee.ImageCollection('USDA/NASS/CDL').filterDate('2017-01-01','2017-12-31').first() 
task_config = {
 'scale': my_scale,
 'region': geometry,
 'fileFormat':'TFRecord'
   }

f1 = medianSent.select(['B1_median','B2_median','B3_median'])


taskSent = ee.batch.Export.image(f1,fname+"_Sent",task_config)
taskSent.start()
```

I expect the output to be readable in python so I can covert into numpy. In case of file format 'tfrecord', I expect the file to be downloaded in my drive.

Comment: can you provide an example image file that cannot be opened?

Answer (score 3):

I think you should think about the following things:

## File format

If you want to open your file with PIL or OpenCV, and *not* with TensorFlow, you would rather use GeoTIFF. Try with this format and see if things are improved.

## Saving to drive

Normally saving to your Drive is the default behavior. However, you can try to force writing to your drive:

```
ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(image=f1, ...)
```

You can further try to setup a folder, where the images should be sent to:

```
ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(image=f1, folder='foo', ...)
```

In addition, the [Export data help page](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/exporting) and this [tutorial](https://geoscripting-wur.github.io/Earth_Engine/) are good starting points for further research.

Comment: GeoTIFF works but I can't save with TFRecord, and yes I want to use it with tensorflow. The earth engine documentation states that we can save it with TFRecords. Thanks in advance.